# React 17.0.2 Module not found: Can't resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 files - 1 component and 1 service file. Component is trying to import services but throw following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/services/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/andonmitev/Desktop/House of entertaiment/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js' in '/Users/andonmitev/Desktop/House of entertaiment/client'
```

This is how service file looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default () => axios.get('http://localhost:4000/');
```

and this is how component file looks like:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import getBase from './services';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await getBase();
    })();
  }, []);

  return <h1>House of entertaiment</h1>;
}

export default App;
```

Files structure:

service -> client/src/services/index.js

component -> client/src/App.js -> (same level with the service folder)

Any ideas? Autocomplete import correctly, by clicking on the import file opens the correct services, haven't been in react for a while and I'm feeling like i'm missing something or it's just the new version

UP:

In general cannot import even a component:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Revert from 17.0.2 to 17.0.0 fix the issue but it's kinda work around :)